# Popup window in PHP?

Tags: php, popupwindow

here's a quick question:

How do you make a window pop up for your error handling in php?
Is javascript the only way to do this or is there a way to do this in PHP?

i have a PHP-file, and one of the lines of code is the following:

```
 echo implode('<br />', $errors);
```

This line of code catches all the errors coming from my form, as following:

```
 if (strlen($_POST['name'])<3) $errors[] = 'De naam van uw bedrijf moet minstens 3 letters bevatten';
  if (strlen($_POST['number'])<9) $errors[] = 'Uw nummer moet minstens 9 nummers bevatten';
  if (!preg_match($regexp_mail, $_POST['email'])) $errors[] = 'Onjuist E-mailadres';
```

when somebody presses submit on my form, the errors will show themselves on a separate page, i want this in a pop-up window.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What would happen if i'm submitting your form and I have a popup blocker which stops your site making the window? or I have JS Turned off?

Comment: Excellent point, did not think of that, hmmm, any ideas on how i can keep my error handling on the same page?

Comment: By error handling? You mean reporting fatal, notice, user, warnings, depreciated errors? or errors from a HTML form not filled correctly?

Comment: @JoeriFastenaekels In the case Daryl laid out, you literally can't do it on the same page, but can do it by posting back to the same page, checking for errors, re-displaying the form if there are any, and redirecting if there aren't to simulate that effect. No matter what it will require a server request.
(That's assuming HTML form validation from the last line of your question)

Comment: i mean the form not correctly filled in, like if somebody fills in an e-mailadress without the @-sign. my code catches these mistakes and lists the errors once thesubmit button is pushed

Comment: @jimcavoli depending on the OPs meaning of error handling, Yes. all the significant error reporting such as `fatal... etc` cannot be on one page, but HTML form errors can

Comment: @JoeriFastenaekels Give me a few to write up example code and I will post as an answer

Comment: Thank you @Jimcavoli, that's the anwser to my question

Comment: @DarylGill Okay, to be fair, if we assume HTML5 compliance, sure, some form validation could be done by the browser by the given markup, but that only covers a few specific cases in all browsers, and I wasn't assuming HTML5 conformance in the first place

Comment: @jimcavoli I am not that up to date on HTML5, I have other people on my team who work with that, I only work with basic HTML. My answer is coming

Comment: @jimcavoli I have posted my answer how I would perform a very basic form validation from server sided scripting and present errors on the same page as the HTML Form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a popup javascript is required. Put this in your header:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("I am an alert box!"); // this is the message in ""
}
</script>
```

And this in your body:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Show alert box">
```

When the button is pressed a box pops up with the message set in the header.

This can be put in any html or php file without the php tags.

-----EDIT-----

To display it using php try this:

```
<?php echo '<script>myfunction()</script>'; ?>
```

It may not be 100% correct but the principle is the same.

To display different messages you can either create lots of functions or you can pass a variable in to the function when you call it.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, although, i need the echo from my errorhandling from my PHP file to show in the alert box :)

Comment: All you have to do is call the function using php: echo '<script>myfunction()</script>'; This might not be 100% correct but the principle is the same.

Comment: thx, problem is solved!

Comment: @NoLiver92 for future reference, posting a URL to w3schools might earn your answer a few down votes. Why? read here: www.w3fools.com

Comment: For something as simple as this I don't think there is any reason to stress over using a better reference than w3schools. Even w3fools states that it works just fine for elementary tasks.

Comment: w3fools now says: "Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns"

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use JS to open the popup, though you can put it on the page conditionally with PHP, you're right that you'll have to use a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server-side thus you have to use a client-side technology which is capable of showing popup windows: JavaScript.

So you should output a specific JS block via PHP if your form contains errors and you want to show that popup.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['Register']))
    {
        $ErrorArrays = array (); //Empty array for input errors 

        $Input_Username = $_POST['Username'];
        $Input_Password = $_POST['Password'];
        $Input_Confirm = $_POST['ConfirmPass'];
        $Input_Email = $_POST['Email'];

        if (empty($Input_Username))
        {
            $ErrorArrays[] = "Username Is Empty";
        }
        if (empty($Input_Password))
        {
            $ErrorArrays[] = "Password Is Empty";
        }
        if ($Input_Password !== $Input_Confirm)
        {
            $ErrorArrays[] = "Passwords Do Not Match!";
        }
        if (!filter_var($Input_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $ErrorArrays[] = "Incorrect Email Formatting";
        }

        if (count($ErrorArrays) == 0)
        {
            // No Errors
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($ErrorArrays AS $Errors)
            {
                echo "<font color='red'><b>".$Errors."</font></b><br>";
            }
        }
    }

?>

    <form method="POST"> 
        Username: <input type='text' name='Username'> <br>
        Password: <input type='password' name='Password'><br>
        Confirm Password: <input type='password' name='ConfirmPass'><br>
        Email: <input type='text' name='Email'> <br><br>

        <input type='submit' name='Register' value='Register'>


    </form>
```

This is a very basic PHP Form validation. This could be put in a `try` block, but for basic reference, I see this fit following our conversation in the comment box.

What this script will do, is process each of the post elements, and act accordingly, for example:

```
    if (!filter_var($Input_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $ErrorArrays[] = "Incorrect Email Formatting";
        }
```

This will check:

> if $Input_Email is not a valid email. If this is not a valid E-mail, then a message will get added to a empty array.

Further down the script, you will see:

```
    if (count($ErrorArrays) == 0)
    {
        // No Errors
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($ErrorArrays AS $Errors)
        {
            echo "<font color='red'><b>".$Errors."</font></b><br>";
        }
    }
```

Basically. if the array count is not 0, errors have been found. Then the script will print out the errors.

**Remember, this is a reference based on our conversation in the comment box, and should be used as such.**

Comment: Yeah, we're on the same page here, just missing each other a little in the comments as to what we meant. Friendly tip: using a > over an == in your if will let you condense the control structure to if(condition) { foreach(errors{ ...} } rather than having the extra else block. Spot-on with the explanation here though.

Comment: @jimcavoli Got where your coming from, but i'm on a board of basic coders, so I need to dumb down the code until they learn the easier methods. Why don't I teach them? Learn from their mistakes; habits keep following across, but yeah. is this what you was looking for?

Comment: yes, thank you, this will do the job even better!